# Instance Eq at Haskell -> Non-exhaustive pattern

Tags: haskell

I am trying to declare an instance using haskell, here i have my data type:

```
data Classification = Aproved Int
                    | Denied
                    | Missing
                    deriving (Show)
```

And the instance declared:

```
instance Eq Classificacao where
    Denied     == Denied    = True
    Missing    == Missing   = True
    Aproved x  == Aproved y = y==x
```

When i try to compare the data constructors, it gives me the error Non-exhaustive pattern , if i use at GHCi `Denied==Missing`

What should i do? I am learning still.

Comment: That's because expression `Denied == Missing` does not have a defined value. If you want everything else evaluate to `False` then you need to add `_ == _ = False` at the end - otherwise it will evaluate to bottom (unspecified value).

Comment: Put `:set -Wall` in your .ghci file and the compiler will warn you about this mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a final pattern match to test for any other combination of inputs as `False`, like so:

```
instance Eq Classification where
Denied     == Denied    = True
Missing    == Missing   = True
Aproved x  == Aproved y = y==x    
x == y = False
```

Comment: Thank you so much shree.pat18. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @skills Tip: Since the last case is to handle everything else, we don't really need to name the expressions `x` or `y` - we could write `_ == _ = False` without affecting the result.